# Why does the getter() of mock object return null?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, aws-sdk, spock

I have a class `ResolverChainContext`:

```
public class ResolverChainContext {
  private AWSCredentialsProvider assumeRoleCredentials;
}
```

and in the `setup()` in a unit test (Groovy and Spock), I populate the above field with Mock:

```
def setup() {
  def ctx = ResolverChainContext.builder().build()

  ctx.setAssumeRoleCredentials(Mock(AWSCredentialsProvider.class))
}
```

Next in my test case, I call a method `getDynamoDBCredentialsV2()` which I want to get the `v1Credentials` from `getDynamoDBCredentials()` which comes from the Mock object in `setup()` step:

```
public interface AWSCredentialsProvider {
    AWSCredentials getCredentials();

    void refresh();
}

protected AWSCredentialsProvider getDynamoDBCredentials() {
    final AWSCredentialsProvider fasCredentials = resolverChainContext.getFasCredentials();
    final AWSCredentialsProvider roleCredentials = resolverChainContext.getAssumeRoleCredentials();
    if (null == fasCredentials || !invokerConfig.isUseCallerCredentials()) {
        return roleCredentials;
    } else {
        return fasCredentials;
    }
}

protected AwsCredentialsProvider getDynamoDBCredentialsV2() {

    AWSCredentials v1Credentials = getDynamoDBCredentials().getCredentials();

    blahblahblah;
}
```

The problem is I will get `null` for `v1Credentials`.

When I debug it, the type of `roleCredentials` is "Mock for type AWSCredentialsProvider". And after calling `getCredentials()` on it, it gets `null`.

Is this because I use Groovy in a wrong way? How could I make `v1Credentials` the object it should be? Should I use Mock/Stub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns null since behavior for `AWSCredentialsProvider#getCredentials` not defined.

From the doc of [interaction based testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html) of Spock, when a behavior is not defined on a mocked object method, its default value will be returned, in your case default value for `Object` is `null`

> Initially, mock objects have no behavior. Calling methods on them is allowed but has no effect other than returning the default value for the method’s return type (false, 0, or null). An exception are the Object.equals, Object.hashCode, and Object.toString methods

To overcome this you might want to define the behavior for `AWSCredentialsProvider#getCredentials` method call using `stubbing` [as explained in the doc](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_stubbing).